# Do we need both? [django-model] Vs [django-models]

Tags: discussion, retag-request, tag-synonyms

I came across an edit in the review queue where a >2.5k user had changed a question with the tag [django-model](/questions/tagged/django-model) to [django-models](/questions/tagged/django-models).

Do we need both?

Should we get rid of [django-model](/questions/tagged/django-model) (singular) given that if you've typed that in, you can just click the pluralised version anyway.

Any question related to a model, would apply in the plural anyway.

Answer (score 1):

It's on [the list](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135985/195089) of tags which differ only by hyphens or pluralization that need cleaning up, now that the system doesn't allow creation of tags which only differ in that way.

I've been picking away at it, there are only ~30 [django-model](/questions/tagged/django-model) questions left now, so manually removing the rest shouldn't be difficult. I've just been doing a small batch at a time to avoid flooding the front page.

Comment: Okay, I just edited the remainder of them. Should be clear to blam now.